# How to have automated updates on postman collections?

Tags: postman, developer-tools, postman-collection-runner

So I want to make developer experience better for my team by sharing postman collections with whoever needs it. At the moment we are just sending postman collections via Microsoft Teams (chat system) which isn't very user friendly and updates are also hard to keep track of. One idea I had was to put the collections on GitHub and then people can just pull it down and import the collection they need into postman. However this will still require someone to keep track of it and update it constantly. Does anyone have any other ideas how these can be kept up to date without having an 'owner'?

Comment: Could you expand on this please - "At the moment we are just sending it via Teams which isn't very user friendly and updates are also hard to keep track of" Do you mean a Team Workspace?

Comment: Just edited the description! I meant Microsoft Teams :)

Comment: Do you use a Team Workspace? Sharing the collection here would sync things and make it up to date and all members would be able to work on the same thing.

Comment: Is that a feature in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: I don't know but it is in Postman. Create a free team, invite you're team members, share the collection to the team workspace, everyone in that Workspace can work on the same up to date collection.